# regexp: Dutch and Arabic names

Tags: regex

I'd like to create regexp that help me validate Dutch and Arabic names
These names consist of three parts:

**First:** only letters, minimum two maximum length of three characters, this part is an option;
**Second:** only letters, minimum two maximum length of three characters, this part is an option;
**Third:** only letters minimum two characters maximum lengt, this part is mandatory;

Valid examples

```
Kohl
Duerr
van Doe
de Hoofdoorp
van der Saar
Al Ahmazi
ibn
```

Comment: `/^(van( der)?|de|idn)?/` ?? ...for starters.

Comment: This seems pretty straightforward. Have you done any research into regular expressions and how to write them and tried something on your own?

Comment: but your example conatins spaces. You didn't mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three options I see:

1. `([a-zA-Z]{2,3} ){0,2}([a-zA-Z]{2,})` This will match zero to two capital or lowercase two-or-three-letter sequences followed by a space, followed by two to infinite capital or lowercase letters. See an example of this regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/yI7uJ3).
2. `([a-z]{2,3} ){0,2}([a-z]{2,})` This is the same as the last one, but requires the "case-insensitive" flag. Activating this flag differs between languages, but it can often be achieved like this: `/([a-z]{2,3} ){0,2}([a-z]{2,})/i`. See an example of this regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/eR8tC9).
3. `([A-Z][a-z]{1,2} |[a-z]{2,3} ){0,2}([A-Z][a-z]{1,}|[a-z]{2,})` This regex is similar to the others, but has one major difference: only the first letter of each word can be capitalized. Otherwise, it does the same thing. See an example of this regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/nE8sU8).

Answer (score 0):

This is all what you need:

```
/^(\w{2,3} )?(\w{2,3} )?(\w{2,3})$/
```

- `^` matches the beginning of the line.
- `\w` matches a word.
- `{2,3}` means something between 2 and 3 characters.
- `?` makes it optional.
- `$` matches the end of the line.

Comment: how it matches the names which contain spaces?

Comment: The question does not ask for spaces, it asks for three parts. Yet @nonr, the third part seems not to have a maximum length.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!